# How to pass data between sibling components in Angular, by 'sending the message/calling the function' from ngOnInit()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I want to send message from ComponentA to ComponentB. And I am using service for that. Here is the code-
My problem is if I call sendInfoToB() from componentA's html file (event hooked to a button click), then I'm recieving the message in componentB /getting
console.log(this.check); and console.log(message); 's values in the console.. but when I call this.sendInfoToB(true); from componentA's ngOnInit() then I get no message in console for componentB. I want the message when I call from componentA's ngOnInit. How can I achieve that? Please help. Thank you in advance.

**ComponentA.ts**

```
constructor(private siblingService: SiblingService,) {}

public dataX: boolean = false;
someFunc(){
//some calculation returning true
  this.dataX = true;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.someFunc();
    this.sendInfoToB();
}

sendInfoToB() {
    this.siblingService.communicateMessage(dataX);
}
```

**message.service.ts**

```
export class SiblingService {
    sendMessage = new Subject();
    constructor() {}

    communicateMessage(msg) {
        this.sendMessage.next(msg);

    }
}
```

**ComponentB.ts**

```
constructor(private sibService: SiblingService,) {}

ngOnInit() {
        
        this.sibService.sendMessage.subscribe((message) => {
            this.check = message;
            console.log(this.check);
            console.log(message);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely this has to do with order of operations. Component A is created and sends the message, then Component B gets created and subscribes to new messages. Since you are using a Subject it only gives you messages sent *after* you subscribe to it.

The easiest strategy to this is to use a BehaviorSubject.

```
export class SiblingService {
    sendMessage = new BehaviorSubject();
    constructor() {}

    communicateMessage(msg) {
        this.sendMessage.next(msg);

    }
}
```

The other way is to send the message after the init happens, like on a click event.